# Positioning an element relative to another one

Tags: jquery, position

I want to assign `xmenu-toggle` class to an element that when clicked a menu  appear in the left-botton side of it. I tried following, but position of menu will be changed in successive clicks. What's wrong?

```
    $('.xmenu-toggle').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var pos=$(this).offset();
        $(this).siblings('.xmenu').offset({top:pos.top+10,left:pos.left+10}).toggle();
    })
```

Html:

```
<div class="xmenu-toggle">Click me!</div>
<div class="xmenu">I am the menu, I have relative position</div>
```

Comment: Could you kindly show your HTML markup with this?

Comment: You want `xmenu` to move to the bottom-left corner of `xmenu-toggle`? Or is `xmenu` initially hidden and you want it to appear in that location?

Comment: @DevlshOne xmenu is initially hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with the placement of the `.toggle()`. I moved it to before the `.offset()` and it came up consistently in the same spot.

```
 $('.xmenu-toggle').click(function (event) {
     var offset = $(this).offset();

     $(this).parent().find('.xmenu').toggle().offset({
         top: offset.top + 10,
         left: offset.left + 10
     });

 });
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/cAGNC/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Not that I could find. Logically, if you think about it, if the element is still hidden, it will have difficulty fixing positions. the `.toggle()` beforehand allows it to secure some positions on the rendered page before the positions can be adjusted.